# Multiple parts created while inserting in Hive table

Tags: hive, compression

I have a hive table (with compression) with definition like

```
create table temp1 (col1 string, col2 int)
partitioned by (col3 string, col4 string) 
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ',' 
escaped by '\\' 
lines terminated by '\n'
stored as sequencefile;
```

When I do a simple select and insert (no reducers running) from another hive table to this table i see a unique pattern, data in this table with compression gets split in high no of files of very small size (**table 1** : at times 1gb data gets split over 200-300 files thus increasing the no of blocks consumed though it should have spanned only 16blocks) due to this very high no of maps are formed when I query this new table. File size does not go beyond 245mb (**table 2**). Is there a setting to restrict this to 64mb (or multiple of 64mb or just a single file) as my block size is 64 mb and hence excess blocks will not get created.

**TABLE 1**

**Name      |    Type       |    Size       |    Block Size**

000000_0        |    file       |    30.22MB        |    64 MB

000001_0        |    file       |    26.19MB        |    64 MB

000002_0        |    file       |    25.19MB        |    64 MB

000003_0        |    file       |    24.74MB        |    64 MB

000004_0        |    file       |    24.54MB        |    64 MB

..........

000031_0        |    file       |    0.9MB      |    64 MB

**TABLE 2**

**Name      |    Type       |    Size       |    Block Size**

000000_0        |    file       |    245.02MB       |    64 MB

000001_0        |    file       |    245.01MB       |    64 MB

000002_0        |    file       |    244.53MB       |    64 MB

000003_0        |    file       |    244.4MB        |    64 MB

000004_0        |    file       |    198.21MB       |    64 MB

Answer (score 4):

have solved the issue thanks to Bryan's who highlighted hive variables that control the query output format.
I tested setting following hive variables in a session:
`set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true`
`set hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000`
`set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000`

So now inside a partition I am getting compressed files of size ~ 256mb.
To permanently set these variables create a .hiverc file with the same statements in home directory of that user.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The key part of the create table query that causes this is the `partitioned by`.  This splits up the data into files and directories for each combination of the columns used.  This allows for querying quickly on sets of them, but can create a large quantity of mappers when querying the entire table.

I suggest you either reconsidering your usage of `partitioned by` or deal with the consequences of it.

Does this usage of a large amount of blocks hurt you tremendously? As long as you are not creating millions of files/directories way below the block size you shouldn't have many issues with your NameNode handling them.

As for the file sizes take a look at this:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration

Pay special attention to `hive.merge.mapfiles`, `hive.merge.mapredfiles`, `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize`, `hive.merge.size.per.task`

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thanks for the reply but this issue is not because of partitioning because files like 000000_0,000001_0,000002_0 ... are formed inside a single partition. For example if my partition is for a month and there is 1GB comressed data for that month then this data is split over 200-300 files with names as above and each part less than 64mb.so the file which should have spanned 16blocks now spans 200-300blocks. Just imagine this happening with 40-50TB data. a simple query starts creating thousands of maps and causing a lot of delay.

Comment: meanwhile I will explore the mentioned HIVE configuration variables, thanks again.