# Hive Query spitting out many files in S3

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, hive

I have the following query.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 
'file_path' 
SELECT name, gender, action, month, F.id
FROM F
INNER JOIN D ON F.id = D.id
WHERE month  = 201612
```

Table D is only 5 distinct IDs and I simply want to extract the variables I have listed from F where the `id` is equal in both F and D. The query works but I am getting roughly 700 or so files in my S3 bucket, the majority of which are completely empty, aka 0 bytes. Any reason as to why this might be happening?

Comment: That's more or less the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317434/hive-splits-orc-files-on-small-parts and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263944/multiple-parts-created-while-inserting-in-hive-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that each reducer in the mapreduce job will produce a file of its own.

This can be solved by first running the following two commands in your hive shell:

```
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
set hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
```

Comment: No need for TEZ, just use `hive.merge.mapfiles` + `hive.merge.mapredfiles` + `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize` cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties